# ngrx/effect passing data to the operators

Tags: javascript, angular, ngrx

I have a scenario where I have to get the request payload passed when the service fails so I can return back along with error response. My code goes like below.

```
@Effect() doGetEvents$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$
.ofType(EVENTS)
.switchMap((action) => {
  let eventDate = action.payload.date;
  return this.http.service(action.payload);
})
.map(res => {
  // success
  if (res.status) {
    return CustomActions.prototype.eventsResponse({ type: EVENTS_RESPONSE, payload: res.payload });
  }

  //failure
  return CustomActions.prototype.EventsErrorResponse({
    type: CustomActions.EVENTS_ERROR_RESPONSE,
    payload: {
      status: res.status,
      errorMessage: res.errorMessage,
      billDate: '10/01/2016', // <--- I need the eventDate got from the above switchMap
      errorType: CustomActions.EVENTS + '_ERROR'
    }
  });

});
```

I tried passing like

```
.switchMap((action) => {
   let eventDate = action.payload.date;
   return [eventDate, this.http.service(action.payload)];
 })
```

but this won't execute the `http` call and won't return the response on `.map()` args.

Also the are options to make the `eventDate` outside the scope of Effects and assign it when service fails but it is not a cleaner approach, there should be some way passing data round not sure what I missed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to include information from the payload, along with the HTTP service's result, you can use the `map` operator, like this:

```
.switchMap((action) => {
  return this.http
    .service(action.payload)
    .map(result => [action.payload.date, result]);
})
.map(([date, result]) => { ... })
```

Comment: this is what I was looking for, my bad that I didn't think through the "normal" http service way but instead `Observable` way :D